# How to use constant for Spring Security hasRole

Tags: jsp, spring-security

I have a JSP with Spring Security. I have a simple tag that determines if the user has an `ADMIN` role like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
```

and works fine.  I am now trying to implement across the site with many roles, so I have a `UserAccess` class with static Strings as constants for all my roles. so I try this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole(UserAccess.ADMIN)">
```

But this is throwing:

```
Field or property 'UserAccess' cannot be found on object of type 
'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
```

The class is in the classpath, I can access it with `<% .. %>` etc...
What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 9):

To reference an instance inside `hasRole` you need to use the special `T` operator and use fully qualified name of the class.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole(T(package.UserAccess).ADMIN)">
```

Comment: Is this syntax documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Missing single quotes perhaps? Try this:

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('UserAccess.ADMIN')">
```