# Thymeleaf , change sec:authorize hasRole string parameter to Java constant

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I would like to use my Java class constants with hasRole in my Thymeleaf template.

Today I use :

```
<div sec:authorize="${hasRole('USR')}">
...
</div>
```

But I would like to use my constants (declared inside my java class)

```
public class Consts{
  public static final String USR_CONST = "USER"; 
}
```

How can I change the string value ('USR' , hasRole parameter ) to constant USR_CONST ?

Comment: Not sure about thymeleaf but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19111668/1700321).

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr . I going to try it , if it works fine I'll post your advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use constant for Spring Security hasRole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108256/how-to-use-constant-for-spring-security-hasrole)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SpEl [Type Operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) `T` to access static constants. eg:

```
<div sec:authorize="${hasRole(T(Consts).USR_CONST)}">
    ...
</div>
```

You'll need to specify the fully qualified path to your `Consts` class within the `T(...)`