# Spring Security RolesAllowed and thymeleaf sec:authorize

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a controller and thymeleaf template. Both contain restrictions on the Spring Security roles. I don't like the fact that I write these roles in two places. Can I write an array of roles in one revenge and use it? I tried to do through enum like

```
@RolesAllowed(ALLOWED_ROLES)
```

and

```
public static final String[] ALLOWED_ROLES = {Role.ADMIN.toString(), Role.EDITOR.toString()};
```

, but the compiler wants a constant ([Use Enum type as a value parameter for @RolesAllowed-Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation)). Is there some nice solution to describe the allowed roles in one place?

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_EDITOR"})
public class MenuEditorController {
    ...
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<ul th:fragment = "nav-default">
    <li><a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></li>
    <li sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EDITOR')"><a th:href="@{/admin/menu}">menu editor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Role Enum:

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ADMIN,
    EDITOR,
    CONSULTANT,
    CLIENT;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "ROLE_" + name();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using static variables in Spring annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444856/using-static-variables-in-spring-annotations)

[Multiple roles using @PreAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247649/multiple-roles-using-preauthorize)

[How to use constant for Spring Security hasRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108256/how-to-use-constant-for-spring-security-hasrole)

```
@Controller
//@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(T(ru.knastnt.prj.web.admin.MenuEditorController).ALLOWED_ROLES)")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(@menuEditorController.ALLOWED_ROLES)")
public class MenuEditorController {
    public static final String[] ALLOWED_ROLES = {Role.ADMIN.toString(), Role.EDITOR.toString()};
    ...
```

```
<ul th:fragment = "nav-default">
    <li sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(@menuEditorController.ALLOWED_ROLES)"><a th:href="@{/admin/menu}">menu editor</a></li>
</ul>
```